# javascript form field population from variable in url query string

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to update a text field within a webform with a variable from the url query string using javascript.

I do not have access to target the form id or name, only the field id and name

Example url: www.xyz.com?name=Chris

Example form code:

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Appreciate the help
Regards,
Chris

Comment: you want to get that query string ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use the following function to get the value from the URL.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then use the following code to update the input with the value.

```
document.getElementsByName('Name').value = getParameterByName('name');
```

**update**

if you want to run the code when the page loads, just add the code to the bottom of the page in a script tag! The script will run after the page loads and would change the value on the input using the query string.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do i actually call the get Element line of javascript to parse the variable? Would it be using a body on load event or within the form field itself. Much thanks

Comment: where do you want to get the value and update the input field?

Comment: the value im getting is in the url and i want to add it to the input field so its visible once when the page loads? How would i do this please?

Comment: Im sorry i just tried to do what you said, and i couldnt get it to work in this example: http://content.engagedigital.com.au/Zap/test.html?Name=Test

Answer (score 0):

You can get & extract the query string in JavaScript using the following Lines.

```
var qrStr = window.location.search;
qrStr = qrStr.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
```

to pass value....

```
function PassValue()
 {
   var paramVal = "Hello ";
   window.open("Default.aspx?id=" + paramVal);
  }

   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
   OnClientClick="PassValue();" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: How to i use javascript to add the value from the url into the form field please? Is it via a body onload event, or would i put the JS call directly in the field value tag - i have no idea :s

Comment: u mean to pass a value ?, check i have edited the code above